# AWS SDK C++: How to abort an async upload?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the Amazon AWS SDK for C++ to upload files to S3.
My program makes a series of `s3_client.PutObjectAsync(request)` calls all at once. At some point later, I want abort the upload of all files that haven't been uploaded yet. How can I do this?

Thanks